# Create a random string of digits

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hashbytes

I need to create a random string of digits of given length

```
CREATE FUNCTION UniqConvert
(@calue as varchar(max),
@len as int)
```

The output should be of the length `@len`
and should be unique per input `@value`

I already asked similar question:
[Create random string of digits T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310130/create-random-string-of-digits-t-sql)
This one has different concept

Comment: Question seems confused. It sounds like you want to hash an input, but also have variable length output. Are you sure about that? If the output length is shorter than a vanilla hash you will increase the chance of collisions. If larger than a normal hash you will gain nothing, and possibly struggle to use the hash.

Comment: The issue i have is the 'len' stipulation with varchar input and 'uniqueness'. Imagine you pass 'A'.. 'Z' in turn and ask for len = 1. There is an obvious collision. You may know what you require and never do this. Your question does not state that and i think it should. I know it is a silly example but it shows the point i am trying to make.

Comment: Have you considered using one of the 'crypto' hash functions? i know they are expensive but, at first look, would seem to do most what you want. Actually, i am guessing as i do not know your 'use case'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @len int
set @len = 3
DECLARE @Random INT      
DECLARE @Upper INT      
DECLARE @Lower INT
SET @Lower = power(10,@Len-1) ---- The lowest random number      
SET @Upper = power(10,@Len )-1 ---- The highest random number      
SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0) 

select  @Random
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   select Cast(Round(Rand()*power(10,@Len),0) as Varchar(30))
```